# Exclude Span From Global CSS Span Styles Inline

Tags: html, css

Lets say you have a global CSS of:

```
span {color: purple;}
```

Now take this line of code:

```
<h1><span>Hi</span></h1>
```

Is there a way to INLINE exclude it?

I obviously can do this through stylesheets or jquery, but my particular use case would need to basically say, I am just a regular  tag, don't apply any global css span style to me.

Is that even possible?

Comment: Excluding? I don't think so, you probably need to [override it](http://jsbin.com/bixono/1/watch?html,css,output) `h1 span { color: inherit; }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm quiet sure that there's no way *exclude* that element based on its parent, however you could override the applied color - for instance - by using [`inherit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit) value (or any other value you want):

**[Example Here](http://jsbin.com/bixono/1/edit)**

```css
h1 span { color: inherit; }
```

So that the nested `<span>` inherits the color from its parent, the `<h1>`. It is supposed to work on IE 8+.

> **[6.2.1 The 'inherit' value](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#value-def-inherit)**
>
> Each property may also have a cascaded value of 'inherit', which means
>   that, for a given element, the property takes the same specified value
>   as the property for the element's parent. The 'inherit' value can be
>   used to enforce inheritance of values, and it can also be used on
>   properties that are not normally inherited.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  Since we are inserting the span dynamically, it would mean we would have to somehow know the styles to inherit.  Essentially we wouldn't know anything about it, we just say look for this text and wrap it in a span. Thanks for the alternative thoughts!

Comment: @Adam One more thing, in order to override the color of the `<span>` elements which are not directly appended into the `<body>` you could use `:not()` negation pseudo class like so: `:not(body) > span {color: inherit;}` **[Demo Here](http://jsbin.com/bixono/2/edit)**